# How Dev Server Datastore are maintained?

Tags: google-app-engine

Does Google Plugin for Eclipse maintain the datastore at Developer environment?

I went through the google's developer guide, but I could not find any information regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For development environment, the Google Plugin creates indexes and database entities under `WEB-INF directory\appengine-generated` folder where it stores indexes under indexes folder and stores entities in local_db.bin

If you have setup your logging, you should be able to see this information when you start your application locally

```
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: High Replication
    Storage: \war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
```